# Petalinux 2014.4 build error with board_f file

Tags: ubuntu, xilinx, zynq, petalinux

I am trying to build a petalinux kernel for a project. 
The bitstream in vivado compiles just fine, there are a few warnings but they are intended (implied latches, things not in sensitivity lists, etc).

When I get the HDF everything is fine as well, the project is initialized just fine. When I configure the the project everything goes smoothly as well. Nothing out of the ordinary, I am instantiating the basic setup, no changes.

Now when i run `petalinux-build -v` , everything is fine until I get to the board_f files. These fail due to this error.

```
[ALL  ] /home//Desktop/NIX_SNES/build/linux/u-boot/src/u-boot-plnx/common/board_f.c: In function 'init_baud_rate':
[ALL  ] /home//Desktop/NIX_SNES/build/linux/u-boot/src/u-boot-plnx/common/board_f.c:143:46: error: 'CONFIG_BAUDRATE' undeclared (first use in this function)
[ALL  ]   gd->baudrate = getenv_ulong("baudrate", 10, CONFIG_BAUDRATE);
[ALL  ]                                               ^
[ALL  ] /home//Desktop/NIX_SNES/build/linux/u-boot/src/u-boot-plnx/common/board_f.c:143:46: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
[ERROR] make[4]: *** [common/board_f.o] Error 1
[ALL  ] make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs...
```

I have tried in both Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.10 , the errors are both the same.

I cant post the entire build log, but here a link to the log on pastebin
[the error occours on line 2375]
http://pastebin.com/zFkXs8wb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the ZYNQ block I was using didn't instantiate the tcl file from the BSP that I got from the Diligent website. Thus none of the UARTS or any other peripherals were described at all. So I made this manually using a base system template and tested it out, it all works.

In case anyone else comes across this problem.

http://pastebin.com/pE6gRGJ2